# Why doesn't `(show (list elem)) ++ '\n'` work in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, type-conversion

My question is simple, and I'm new to haskell, so this may be an easy question. The following function:

```
my_version_unlines list = [(show (list !! i)) ++ '\n' | i <- [0..(length list)-1]]
```

When I try to use it, I get this error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Char'
```

I also saw that `show ([2]!!0) ++ '\n'` gives the same error message in the GHCi. Could someone please explain this?

Comment: I think your guard expression should rather be ` | i <- [0..((length list)-1)] `. Evaluation of (list !! (length list)) would raise an exception. Classic off-by-one error :-)

Comment: @jpmarinierYep, sorry 'bout that! I couldn't get the code to work at all, so this error never came up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'\n'` is a `Char`. The [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) function appends two *lists* together. A `Char` is not a list. A string however is, since `String` is just an alias for `[Char]`, so a list of `Char`s.

You can thus do this with:

```
my_version_unlines list = [show li ++ "\n" | li <- list]
```

Here the double quotes `"…"` thus indicate a string, wheras single quotes `'…'` are used for a `Char`.

alternatively, we can make use of `map` here:

```
my_version_unlines :: Show a => [a] -> [String]
my_version_unlines = map ((++ "\n") . show)
```

If you however want to convert a list of objects to a `String` separated by lines, it is better to make use of [**`unlines :: [String] -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unlines):

```
my_version_unlines :: Show a => [a] -> String
my_version_unlines = unlines . map show
```

> **Note**: Using [**`(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) is often not a good idea.
>   A list is implemented in Haskell as a linked list, and thus this will take linear time, furthermore the function is *non-total* since
>   for negative indexes, or indexes larger than the length of the list, this will error. It is often better to iterate over the list itself.